# How can I allow public access to parts of Spring Security app using permitAll?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm trying to get a Spring application to allow some requests to public (without login) and some requests to private (with login).

At this point I'd like to just get the public part to work properly.

I have tried most of the example configurations listed on the Spring Security documentation, including all sorts of combinations of anonymous(), and permitAll(). All end up redirecting to the login page.

```java
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/resources/**", "/signup", "/about","/api/home").permitAll()                
            .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")                                    
            .antMatchers("/db/**").access("hasRole('ADMIN') and hasRole('DBA')")      
            .anyRequest().authenticated()                                             
            .and()
        // ...
        .formLogin();
    }
```

**Expected result:** items under permitAll() are accessible without logging in

**Actual result:**

> redirect to login page. This shows up in the log:  2019-06-06
>   17:29:43.593  INFO 56330 --- [           main]
>   o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: any
>   request, [org.sprin...

This leads me to believe that it isn't even reading this configuration. Is there any way to fix this?

Thanks!

UPDATE: I tried adding the websecurity ignores, and it doesn't appear to be working still. It appears to still print the "defaultsecuritychain" error so I feel like this may have something to do with it.

UPDATE 2: Added application.properties file under src/main/resources with this line logging.level.org.springframework.security=DEBUG to make it log debug messages.

pastebin.com/2u9k7eHD

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Turns out that I was missing the @SpringBootApplication annotation all along in one of my source files. Make sure that's in there and perhaps it will work.

Thank you to all who replied!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at http://blog.florian-hopf.de/2017/08/spring-security.html, it may explain your use-case in more detail.

My recommendation is to try and use WebSecurity for static and public resources

```
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/resources/**", "/signup", "/about","/api/home");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your requirements with below configurations. It's a good way to use the URLs which does't require Authentication/Authorization to be placed in `WebSecurity using ignoring instead of HttpSecurity as WebScurity will bypass the Spring Security Filter Chain and reduce the execution time`

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web
        .ignoring()
        .antMatchers("/resources/**", "/signup", "/about","/api/home");
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")                                    
        .antMatchers("/db/**").access("hasRole('ADMIN') and hasRole('DBA')") 
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .yourConfigurations
}
```

When you use `HttpSecurity` and try to `permitAll()` requests. Your requests will be allowed to be accessed from the Spring Security Filter Chain. This is costly as there will be requests other requests which would also come into this filter chain which needs to be allowed or disallowed based on Authentication/Authorization

But when you use `WebSecurity`, any requests to `"/resources/**", "/signup", "/about","/api/home"` will completely by pass the Spring Security Filter Chain all together. It is safe because you don't need any Authentication/Authorization to be in place to see an image or read a javascript file.

Comment: I've tried to implement this solution, however it doesn't appear to be working and the application still redirects to login. Thanks

Comment: Hello @larryqiann Can you please upload your project on git and share the link